# Debugging in Loopback (Node)

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, node-inspector, node-debugger

I'm running into an issues and a question when I debug in loopback (probably the same for any node server/Node Inspector).

1. For some reason in Node Inspector (slc debug or node-debug) when I try
   to use the console option or add a watch expression, hitting return
   doesn't process the command it just returns the cursor to the next
   line.  Do I have some bad version of Node Inspector?

   [image]
2. In loopback I am able to have access to my full application object when running in debug mode (which is a good thing) and I can use that application object to perform domain functions - e.g.

   m.models.accounts.count(function(err,returnCount) 
     { 
        console.log(returnCount) 
     }; 
   );

   Above I'm just getting a count of the number of accounts in the database.  I'd prefer not to deal with promises and simply write something like

   m.models.accounts.count().

   Is there is library or a way to do this?

Comment: If you are using node v6.3 or newer, try the new `--inspect` command line argument which will let you debug with chrome devtools directly, leaving node-inspector out of the picture entirely. Node will print out the URL you need to open in chrome to debug.

Comment: Thank you. That solves my issue #1 - much better (working) interface.  What about question #2?

Comment: For #2 the short answer is no, you can't get a synchronous-style API in the node debugger console. At least not yet. When async/await from ES2017 land in v8 then you'll have a way to do that. Note that `m.models.accounts.count(console.log)` will often suffice for basic WTF debugging.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping there was something else I could do. I like the loopback and the ability to debug from a console which becomes very powerful (like Rails console). But it's verbose to do some basic functions if you always have to deal with callbacks. I found this (https://github.com/GovRight/loopback-console) which seems to be "better". I need to look at their code to understand how they are doing it.